# Append A Column To A Matrix Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, append

I am iterating through each column in a matrix and performing an operation on each element in that column. Problem is, how do I add this column to the end of another matrix?

```
normalized_features = [];
for col = 1:6;
    cur_col = features(:, col);
    for i = 1:length(cur_col);
        elm = cur_col(i);
        elm = (elm - features_mean(col)) / features_standard_dev(col);
        cur_col(i) = elm;
        if i == length(cur_col)
            % append cur_col to normalized_features matrix
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append the column like this:

```
normalized_features = [normalized_features cur_col];
```

This operation concatenates the two matrices horizontally. See the [Matrices and Arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/matrices-and-arrays.html#btcd6e5-1) documentation for more information.

Comment: this seems to work, thanks! would you mind explaining your answer? (p.s. i just started matlab yesterday)